# How do I programmatically turn off the wavy red lines in a Microsoft Word document via VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, spell-checking

Is there anyway to disable spell checking on a per document basis via VBA for MS Word?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can mark the current document as already spell-checked:

```
ActiveDocument.SpellingChecked = True
```

or you can disable spell checking for a range of text:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.NoProofing = True
```

You can also simply [disable the display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178124%28office.12%29.aspx) of the red squiggles:

```
ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = False
```

---

Note that the same things can be done for grammar-checking (green squiggles); *e.g.*:

```
ActiveDocument.GrammarChecked = True
```

will mark the current document as already grammar-checked, thus effectively disabling it.

Comment: 'ActiveDocument.Range.NoProofing = True` does it for the whole doc in mso365

Comment: @Piecevcake: Yes; if you want only part of the document, you need to pick / select the respective range first and then set the `NoProofing` property on that range.

Answer (score 4):

```
ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = False
```